# Why function cannot read array element in loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple function that only checks if the fourth element of an array is bigger or not.

Somehow I am getting and error `TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined`

And I have no idea why... Can someone tell me what is wrong with this function?

```js
var pasujace = [
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00063746", 1000.0],
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00063743", 100.0],
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00063743", 100.0],
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00056983", 300.0]
];
var roznica = 50;

function lastOne(arr, num) {
  var nowa = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][3] > num) {
      nowa.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return nowa
}

const last = lastOne(pasujace, roznica);
console.log(last)
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/liqiwinale/1/edit?js,console). I had to change the first three items in each array to a string for this to be valid code, however.

Comment: do you think its because of google sheets?

Comment: I think it's because of something that's not shown here. Maybe the array has an empty slot would be my best guess.

Comment: Well the full array consists of arrays like this one `[HAT, A4205022, L00063746, 1000.0, , , , 1161P38051, , , , 4720021465 ]` so there are empty slots but after the element I want to check

Comment: We added quotes for you... Does it work now? Can you please update it to a more relevant example that looks like what you are testing?

Comment: Thank you! It is working on snippet so it should work on google-sheets as well... but it's not ...

Comment: I don't know why but when I change `arr[i][3] > num` to `arr[0][3] > num` I am not getting error and it works but well its not a loop anymore

Comment: @Pimo it works if you hardcode the index because the item at index zero exists. You're not going through the missing item in your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a filter

```js
var pasujace = [
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00063746", 1000.0],
  [],
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00063743", 100.0],
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00063743", 100.0],
  ["BLANK", "AAA"],
  ,
  ["BLANK", "AAA", "MISSING"],
  ["BLANK", "A4205022", "L00056983", 300.0]
];
var roznica = 100;

const lastOne = (arr, num) => arr.filter(item => {
  if (!item || item.length < 3 || isNaN(item[3])) return false;
  return item[3] > num
});


const last = lastOne(pasujace, roznica);
console.log(last)
```

Comment: The problem OP describes is likely due to `arr` just not having an element, as opposed to the element being an array with length less than 3. Whether the missing element is an empty slot or a literal `null` or `undefined` would change how this can be handled. Moreover, it's entirely possible that it's fixable via changing how `arr` is created.

Comment: with this solution I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` so I guess its not the problem of the code again

Comment: See update to handle missing entries

Comment: It is working now, thanks a lot!